# Trouble understanding how to create a collection in my trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

Hello and thank you for taking the time to reading my question,

Many of you have already helped me out a lot with great ideas and pointers. One of them is to create a collection and I am puzzled on how i would do this especially in an optimized manner.

I am creating an opportunity trigger with before update and after update, it will in the end create a Contract(Service Agreement), I need to gather information from the opportunity, its child quote(there is a synced checkbox that marks the quote as the correct quote) and verify is there is a child contract already created.

The code:

```
    List<Opportunity> opp =     [SELECT
                                      Id, StageName, (SELECT Id FROM Service_Contracts__r), 
                                      (SELECT Id From Quotes )
                                     FROM
                                      Opportunity 
                                     WHERE
                                      Id IN:oppIds
                                     ];
```

When I try to run this in the 'Execute Anonymous' the quote and service contract are not present.

Peter mentioned "Related objects (either parent or child) are not populated in Trigger.new/old. Best practice would be to do a "collect" step with the initial for loop to get only the records you want to work with, make the DB trip with SOQL"

So how would I populate with SOQL efficiently?

In my execute I used an opp id to pull up relevant data (WHERE ID = '0123456')

```
System.debug(oppsFromDb); // Pulls the opp information but nothing on quotes or Scontracts

System.debug(oppsFromDb[0].Quotes); //runs but no variables.
```

Thank you again for all your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the Quote existed before the Opportunity was being updated, you should be able reference the 'Quotes' relationship in the before/ after update trigger on Opportunity.

The relationship fields are not available in before/after insert triggers, in which case you have to aggregate ids and then query for them.

eg

```
trigger OpportunityBefore on Opportunity (before insert){

Map<Id, Opportunity> accIdsMap = new Map<Id, Opportunity>{};

for(Opportunity opp : trigger.new){
System.debug(opp.Account.Name); //this will not work as the relationship is not available
accIds.add(opp.AccountId, opp); //this id will be available, so lets collect account ids
}

//now we will query for collected account ids
for(Account acc : [Select Id, Name from Account where Id in :accIdsMap.keySet()])
System.debug(acc.Name + ' is the account for ' + accIdsMap.get(acc.Id) + ' Opportunity');

}
```

If I've understood you right, this [blog post](http://cloudnow.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/apex-bloopers-why-art-thou-null/) might help.

Comment: Hi techtrekker, thank you for your response. You are correct that is what I want to do, and my trigger is on update. I didn't test it from the trigger but just copied the code and placed it on the Execute Anonymous tab. I will look into the post you have mentioned. If I still have some problems I will add more of my code so it makes more sense. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

This is strange. I just ran:

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT 
                              Id, (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities) 
                          FROM 
                              Account 
                          WHERE 
                              Id = '001F000000jlUsTIAU' 
                          LIMIT 1
];

System.debug(accounts.get(0).Opportunities);
```

I got the following result:

> 15:24:24:094 USER_DEBUG
>   [3]|DEBUG|(Opportunity:{RecordTypeId=012F0000000j9RCIAY,
>   AccountId=001F000000jlUsTIAU, Id=006F000000IlAmXIAV})

This would tend to indicate that the call is working properly.

---

However, this is really interesting. I ran the following:

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT 
                              Id, (SELECT Id FROM Opportunities__r) 
                          FROM 
                              Account 
                          WHERE 
                              Id = '001F000000jlUsTIAU' 
                          LIMIT 1
];

System.debug(accounts.get(0).Opportunities__r);
```

and got the following result:

> 15:40:40:071 USER_DEBUG [3]|DEBUG|()

This would indicate that apparently you can type any relationship into SOQL and if the relationship isn't valid it just returns nothing.

**EDIT:** Ran this in a brand new org and it didn't compile. I guess someone made a custom relationship between `Opportunity` and `Account` in the org I was in. Not sure why, but this makes much more sense! Disregard the above section on `Opportunities__r` and the issue of this compiling!

---

Using the above logic, I tried this:

```
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT 
                              Id, (SELECT Id FROM Non_Existent_Object__r) 
                          FROM 
                              Account 
                          WHERE 
                              Id = '001F000000jlUsTIAU' 
                          LIMIT 1
];

System.debug(accounts.get(0).Non_Existent_Object__r);
```

This instantly returned:

> line 1, column 26: Didn't understand relationship
>   'Non_Existent_Object_*r' in FROM part of query call. If you are
>   attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '*_r'
>   after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the
>   describe call for the appropriate names.

This shows that what I originally thought was incorrect with just allowing any relationship name being a valid option (which makes much more sense). This is much more consistent with my understanding of [Relationship queries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/index_Left.htm#CSHID=sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm|StartTopic=Content%2Fsforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm|SkinName=webhelp).

---

I decided to do a bit more research and using the [sObject Describe methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm) in conjunction with the [ChildRelationship Methods](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_sobject_describe.htm#apex_childRelationship_methods). I ran the following code:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe();
List<Schema.ChildRelationship> relationships = d.getChildRelationships();

String listOfRelationshipNames = '';
for(Schema.ChildRelationship rel:relationships){
    listOfRelationshipNames = listOfRelationshipNames + rel.getRelationshipName() + ', ';
}

System.debug(listOfRelationshipNames);
```

which returned the following:

> 16:02:01:131 USER_DEBUG [9]|DEBUG|null, AccountContactRoles, Feeds,
>   Histories, AccountPartnersFrom, AccountPartnersTo, Shares,
>   ActivityHistories, Assets, Attachments, Cases, Contacts, null, null,
>   Contracts, FeedSubscriptionsForEntity, null, Events, null, null, null,
>   Notes, NotesAndAttachments, OpenActivities, Opportunities,
>   OpportunityPartnersTo, PartnersFrom, PartnersTo, ProcessInstances,
>   ProcessSteps, null, Tasks, null, null

So, tweaking that code a bit to run it for `Opportunity`:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult d = Opportunity.sObjectType.getDescribe();
List<Schema.ChildRelationship> relationships = d.getChildRelationships();

String listOfRelationshipNames = '';
for(Schema.ChildRelationship rel:relationships){
    listOfRelationshipNames = listOfRelationshipNames + rel.getRelationshipName() + ', ';
}

System.debug(listOfRelationshipNames);
```

which returned:

> 16:02:39:094 USER_DEBUG [9]|DEBUG|AccountPartners, ActivityHistories,
>   Attachments, null, null, FeedSubscriptionsForEntity, Events, null,
>   null, null, Notes, NotesAndAttachments, OpenActivities,
>   OpportunityCompetitors, OpportunityContactRoles, Feeds, Histories,
>   OpportunityHistories, OpportunityLineItems, OpportunityPartnersFrom,
>   Shares, Partners, ProcessInstances, ProcessSteps, Tasks

All of this seems kind of out there. I don't even see the `Quotes` child relationship (although this may not be active in my demo org?).

---

Long story short, I am not sure how much this will help you, but this should work. It is most likely an issue with the `Quotes` relationship name being something different than what you are attempting to access. I would try messing around with that. Hopefully someone smarter than me can jump in and help look over what we have found and give you a better answer. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks very much Jesse for looking so much into this, like you I get the same types of errors, and oddly on my schema it shows that they should exist. I could probably just grab the quote id and then do a seperate query but I fear I will just slow down the performance. I will continue to play around with it :)

Comment: Yea, sorry I couldn't help more. That query should work, although I am a bit at a lose because I haven't worked with `Quotes` before. I guess I need to take the advice I always give other and read the documentation! http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_quote.htm